# Lazarus (freepascal) Reading large output from TProcess

Tags: process, stream, freepascal, lazarus

I' m reading large process output data in Lazarus using the TProcess and the suggestions from [this](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#Using_input_and_output_of_a_TProcess) freepascal wiki page.

The wiki page suggests to create a loop to read the process output data like this:

```
// ... If you want to read output from an external process, this is the code you should adapt for production use.

while True do
  begin          
    MemStream.SetSize(BytesRead + 2024); // make sure we have room
    NumBytes := OurProcess.Output.Read((MemStream.Memory + BytesRead)^, READ_BYTES);
    if NumBytes > 0
    then begin
      Inc(BytesRead, NumBytes);
      Write('.') //Output progress to screen.
    end else 
      BREAK // Program has finished execution.
  end;

// "Then read the MemStream to do your job"
```

The wiki page also mentions that the calling program should read from the output pipe to prevent it from getting full.

So, how much data makes the output pipe full?

Why we should use a `MemStream` (TMemoryStream) and not directly read from `OurProcess.Output` stream (using the `bytesAvailable`, etc) in the above loop?

I'm reading 80MB of wav data from a process and I have noticed that both `MemStream` and `OurProcess.Output` streams have the same amount of data! The memory usage gets doubled. So the suggested method from the wiki cannot be considered as efficient or optimized. Or there is something I'm missing?

Comment: Nowadays there are runcommand() macros that return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik output/input streams are a stream form of a pipe, not memory streams. The values you see are retrieved from the OS handle, not from memory allocated to the FPC app per se.

It is just like you can ask for the .size of a file on disk without reading the whole file.

Comment: So the `.output` stream does **not** contain the entire data when `.execute` is completed? And how much data `.output` can hold guaranteed?

Comment: Dear myself, after 6 years, I tell you that there is no guaranteed amount of data in `.output`. Also there is no guarantee that the remainder data is in the `.output` while `.Running` turned from `True` to `False`. You must rely only on the return value of `.Output.Read` and/or `.StdErr.Read`, i.e. if it `0` the handle is closed and there will be no further data to read. Then you may exit your loop or whatever you're doing with it.

Comment: In FPC 3.2.0, look at TProcess.Runcommandloop, it is pretty much a blueprint of the best way to do it.

Comment: I was referring to the `MemStream` that copies the data using `Output.Read` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
    procedure RunExternalAppInMemo(DosApp:String;AMemo:TMemo);

    const READ_BYTES = 2048;
    var
    aProcess: TProcess; //TProcess is crossplatform is best way
    MemStream: TMemoryStream;
    NumBytes: LongInt;
    BytesRead: LongInt;
    Lines: TStringList;
  begin
   // A temp Memorystream is used to buffer the output
   MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   Lines :=TStringList.Create;
   BytesRead := 0;

     aProcess := TProcess.Create(nil);
     aProcess.CommandLine := DosApp;
     aprocess.ShowWindow := swoHIDE;
     AProcess.Options := AProcess.Options + [poUsePipes];

     aProcess.Execute;
     while aProcess.Running do
     begin
       // make sure we have room
       MemStream.SetSize(BytesRead + READ_BYTES);

       // try reading it
       NumBytes := aProcess.Output.Read((MemStream.Memory + BytesRead)^, READ_BYTES);
       if NumBytes > 0 // All read() calls will block, except the final one.
          then Inc(BytesRead, NumBytes)
       else
          BREAK // Program has finished execution.
     end;
     MemStream.SetSize(BytesRead);
     Lines.LoadFromStream(MemStream);
     AMemo.lines.AddStrings(Lines);
     aProcess.Free;
     Lines.Free;
     MemStream.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this problem today, I've modified Georgescu answer, as I wanted Memo to display output stream on the fly

```
procedure RunExternalAppInMemo(DosApp:String;AMemo:TMemo);

    const READ_BYTES = 2048;
    var
    aProcess: TProcess; //TProcess is crossplatform is best way    
    NumBytes: LongInt;
    Buffer: array of byte;    
    
  begin
    // set the size of your buffer
     SetLength(Buffer,READ_BYTES);   
     aProcess := TProcess.Create(nil);
     aProcess.CommandLine := DosApp;
     aprocess.ShowWindow := swoHIDE;
     AProcess.Options := AProcess.Options + [poUsePipes];     
     aProcess.Execute;
     
     while aProcess.Running do
      begin
       // try reading it
       NumBytes := aProcess.Output.Read(Buffer[0], length(buffer)*sizeof(byte)); // I usually do it that way, so I can change Buffer size on if needed
       AProcess.Suspend; //I have no experience with pipes, but it seems way I won loose eny output?
       if NumBytes > 0 then // All read() calls will block, except the final one.
        begin     
            
          AMemo.Lines.Add(Pchar(Buffer);            
          application.ProcessMessages;
          AProcess.Resume; 
        end
       else
          BREAK; // Program has finished execution.         
     end;
     setlength(Buffer,0);
     aProcess.Free;     
  end;
```

Comment: `AProcess.Suspend` (and `Resume`) is not needed. Output is stored in a os buffer and if it's full then execution is blocked until the other end reads from it.

Comment: `NumBytes` should be used to read from buffer using [setString](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/setstring.html), Right now you just assume that the `buffer` is `null` terminated.  Finally I'd just do the loop like `while NumBytes > 0` because it's not guaranteed (I think) that you have read all output at the time that `aProcess.Running` becomes false.

Comment: Please do not make posts that are not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes I agree with the loop, I was working with process that constantly feeds output, stops when terminate - once I read your comment it became obvious it wont always be the case.
About not posting, sorry it's probably silly question but just recently I felt like I should at least try to give something back to the community, probably should find some "general posting rules" or sth - it's not considered an answer because my solution is same as in earlier answer, just add functionality that wasn't part of the question right?